# OpenLayers (2.13.1) zoom/pan has stopped working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, openlayers

I have a legacy product which utilises an older version of OpenLayers (specifically 2.13.1 - I had it on a sversion 2.12 originally and upgraded to 2.13.1 to see if it rectified my problem - it didn't).

The problem is that recently, without any code changes having been made, the zoom in/out and drag-panning do not work - the map just stays where it is, zoomed in at the initial level.

I can see that whenever the zoom or pan controls are triggered, a request is made to a Google Maps URL (e.g. http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/StaticMapService.GetMapImage?1m2&1i524027&2i524088&2e2&3u12&4m2&1u523&2u400&5m5&1e3&5sen-US&6sus&10b1&12b1&token=39368)

However I can also see that this just returns a blank, black image.

I can find no sign of this functionality having been deprecated and I'd really like to avoid the inherent time cost of upgrading to version 3 on a legacy application.

Any ideas? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you try this URL: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.714728,-73.998672&zoom=12&size=400x400 it will give you a static map image. You can read [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) for more information about the static maps image request URL parameters.

Comment: Thanks for that, however I've found that documentation before, and that would require us refactoring to not use the OpenLayers API  (as that is what's generating the current image URLs) and instead to generate the image URLs ourselves - I'm just trying to work out if Google has deprecated the form of the URL used by OpenLayers, causing our problem, or whether it's something else.